# What is the probability a 10 digit phone number contains at most one zero?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A telephone number consists of ten digits, of which the first digit is one of $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ (first digit cannot be zero).  The others can be $0,1,2,3\dots 9$.
What is the probability that zero appears at most once in a telephone number if all the digits are chosen completely at random?

Comment: What have you tried???

Comment: Have you considered the binomial distribution?

Comment: I am new to probability... so I have figured out the total sample space is 9 * 10^9 and that is about it.  Most questions are posed as having at least one occurrence and you calculate the probability of no occurrences.

Comment: contemplated 9^9 * 10 as the numerator but not sure if that is correct

Answer (score 2):

There are $9 \times 10^9$ possible valid numbers:  $1\leftrightarrow 9$ in the first slot and $0 \leftrightarrow 9$ in each of the remaining $9$ slots.

The number of numbers that have exactly zero $0$s is:  $9 \times 9^9$, as there are only $9$ permissible digits for the first slot and $9$ permissible digits ($1\leftrightarrow 9$) in each of the $9$ remaining slots.

The number of numbers that have exactly one $0$ is $9 \times 9^8 \times 9$, as there are $9$ possible digits for the first slot and $9$ possible digits in each of $8$ remaining slots and $9$ choices for which slot must contain the $0$.

Can you put these results together?

Comment: Thank you!  That was what I was trying to work out.

Answer (score 1):

Since $0$ can appear at most once, calculate the probability that it appears one time or zero times and sum them (considering also that the first digit cannot be $0$).

The probability of no $0$ is: $P_0= \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{9}$

The probability of exactly $1$ zero is: $P_1=9\frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{8} = \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{9}$

So you conclude that the probability of the phone number having at most one $0$ is:

$$\boxed{ P = \left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{9}+\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{9} = 2\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{9} }$$

Comment: i think probability of one zero is also $9^9$ as we can choose one place in 9 ways.

Comment: @Aditya_math Oh, you're right, I'll edit it.

Comment: I had thought of that, but I found solution that said the answer was .7748 ~ which I cannot get.

Comment: So when I looked a it ~ I did 9^10/(9*10^9) + (9^9*10)/(9*10^9) which is the same solution you posted but not the .7748... almost three hours...

Comment: YEAH!!! the updated works!!! THANK YOU<<< :)>>>

Comment: @Cathy my first attemp was wrong, I'm sorry. This one's the right one, it's the .7748 you're looking for.

Comment: No worries at all.  I am very appreciate of the help... My mind was all twisted up on this for some reason.  I did the rest of the homework problems no issues, but this just tricked me.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Knowing $0$ cannot be at the first place, we have $9$ more to care about.
Logically, "Appears at most once" is the same as showing $0$ times, or showing $1$ time only. No more!

If each digit is chosen randomly, we have $\frac{1}{10}$ for each, thus making the choice of $0$ being $\frac{1}{10}$ and not zero $1 - \frac{1}{10} = \frac{9}{10}$

What is the probability we won't have a zero anywhere? it is only when we choose those $\frac{9}{10}$ (remember, this is the probability of not choosing a zero) the choices are independent of one another so we multiply:
$$ \overbrace{\frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{10} \cdot \dots \cdot \frac{1}{10}}^{\text{9 times}} = \left ( \frac{9}{10} \right )^9 $$

Now we need to deal with the $1$ zero appearing. What we need to do is first choose a place for it to be, how many places available? $9$. Then we should multiply this by the probability an actual zero would land there i.e. $\frac{1}{10}$ while multiplying the rest to assure we get another digit, not a zero i.e. $$\overbrace{\frac{1}{10}}^{\text{choosing one zero}} \cdot \overbrace{\frac{1}{10} \cdot \frac{1}{10} \cdot \dots \cdot \frac{1}{10}}^{\text{8 times}} = \left ( \frac{9}{10} \right )^9$$

Thus the whole probability is the addition of the two - because it is asking for $0$ zeros *or* $1$ zero.

$$ 2 \cdot \left ( \frac{9}{10} \right)^9 $$

Comment: Thank you!  Seeing it calculated both ways (total number of possible numbers vs fractions) makes it much easier to understand.